# How to use actionPerformed() to check to see if a button has been clicked?

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (text1.equals(e.isSelected())) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
}
```

text1 is my JButton
for some reason, isSelected is not working, anyone know why?
any help is appreciated!

thanks in advance,

-kameron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question raises more questions.

By it's nature, `JButton` does not support the property `isSelected`.  `isSelected` is used by toggle style buttons, like `JRadioButton`, `JCheckBox` and `JToggleButton`.

By the very nature of your question, if the `JButton` is clicked, it will be "selected"

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("text1 has being selected");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`isSelected` is undefined for `ActionEvent`. If the `ActionListener` is the only one registered with the `JButton`, then the code will be simply:

```
text1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

       System.out.println("test");
    }
});
```

Comment: or at least how to make isSelected defined?

Comment: If your button is just a regular button, then you don't need any special checks for the selected state of the component. This only apply to toggle buttons. If the latter is true you can then get the button reference using `getSource`.